# Does Google Pub/Sub queue or topic?

Tags: jms, google-cloud-pubsub, messagebroker

I am familiar with JMS and novice with Google Pub/Sub.

In JMS there are 2 options:

- **Queue**: only one consumer can accept message.
- **Topic**: each consumer accepts each message from the topic

I believe that Google Pub/Sub should support something like this, but a quick Googling didn't help me to answer that question.

Please point me out to the corresponding documentation part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the name "Pub/Sub" indicates, Google Pub/Sub supports publish/subscribes semantics which correspond to JMS topics. It doesn't support point-to-point semantics which correspond to JMS queues, at least not directly.

You can see an overview of the semantics in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview). The "Publisher-subscriber relationships" section may be helpful. To be clear, this documentation does use the word *queue* in two places:

1. In the "Pub/Sub message flow" section: "When a message is acknowledged by the subscriber, it is removed from the subscription's message queue."
2. In the "Common use cases" section: "For example, a large queue of tasks can be efficiently distributed among multiple workers, such as Google Compute Engine instances."

The term *queue* here is being used to refer to the actual *subscription* on the topic (i.e. where the messages are placed for subscribers to consume). Furthermore, the [architectural overview](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/architecture) includes this diagram:
[image: Google Pub/Sub architecture]
This diagram demonstrates how multiple subscribers can receive messages from the same subscription (e.g. for balancing workloads). This would be akin to the "shared subscription" functionality [added for topics in JMS 2](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jms2messaging.html).

Comment: I've read it and it doesn't give direct answer for my question.  Let's even take a look on quote from the page you linked:  **Balancing workloads in network clusters. For example, a large queue of tasks can be efficiently distributed among multiple workers, such as Google Compute Engine instances.**   I expect that here should be queue because in case of topic each worker gets each message and it will a cause that all workers do the same work that is unexpected in general

Comment: Yes, I've found this picture too. It answers my question

Comment: subscriber->subscription is a queue, topic-> subscription is a publish/subscribe

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the answer to this question, and I've found this documentation that describe the behaviour of a queue rather than a topic :

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber

> While a message is outstanding to a subscriber, however, Pub/Sub tries
> not to deliver it to any other subscriber on the same subscription.

So my understanding is that if you want

- a topic behaviour (one to many): you create many subscriptions, each will get a copy of the message
- a queue behaviour : there is a single subscription with multiple clients

On each subscription you can run one or more subscribers for task distribution, where each message is delivered to only one consumer.

Comment: Unlikely round-robin. Most FIFO queue systems will deliver a new task/job to the first client that is ready to take on new work. Imagine a building that is on fire, a well that is nearby, and 10 people with empty buckets. To put out the fire as quickly as possible, the first person who arrives at the well should be the first to receive water. Similarly, the first person to return from the fire with an empty bucket should be the first to get a new bucket of water. Redis queues and blocking pops are a good example: https://redis.io/commands/blpop/