# Migrate a Spring boot application with JMS (ActiveMQ) to GCP's pub-sub

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jms, google-cloud-pubsub

We have a Spring Boot application that uses the standard layer model (Controllers, Services, DAO).

Our service layer is using JMS events to produce & consume events.

We would like to consider migrating from ActiveMQ to Google's Pub-Sub (primarily since there is a managed solution on GCP unlike ActiveMQ).

1. Is it possible to implement a queue using Pub-Sub (e.g. produce once, consume once unlike a topic with multiple consumers/subscribers)?
2. Are there any examples showing Pub-Sub implementation within the model of the 3 layers in Spring (controllers, services, DAO)? All we could find is a simple Pub-Sub application using Spring Boot. We are interested in seeing what change it will require from our service layer which uses an `onMessage(Event e)` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's Pub-Sub doesn't support point-to-point semantics like those specified for JMS queues. However, you may be able to approximate these semantics by using multiple consumers on one subscription on a topic. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59353759/does-google-pub-sub-queue-or-topic/) for more details on that.